# Problem with understanding usage of identify

Tags: r, plot

i need to paint a graph using LakeHuron data in R, single paiting is easy just

```
df= data.frame(LakeHuron)
plot(df)
```

but I need to use identify to sign the years where the point of water was the highest and the lowest

```
df=data.frame(LakeHuron)
df
plot(df)
minimum = min(df)
maximum = max(df)
```

I got those minimum and maximum variables, but how can i use identify to point them on plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to label the years, it may be easiest to do that with `text`.

```
Xmin = which.min(df$LakeHuron)
Xmax = which.max(df$LakeHuron)
Years = 1875:1972

plot(df)
text(x=Years[c(Xmin, Xmax)], y = LakeHuron[c(Xmin, Xmax)], 
    labels=Years[c(Xmin, Xmax)], pos=4)
```

[image: First chart]

If you *really* want to use `identify`,  you can use

```
plot(df)
Years = 1875:1972
identify(x=Years, y=LakeHuron, labels=Years)
```

Then click near the maximum and minimum. Right click and select "stop" when you are done.

Comment: i didnt even know that it's so 'interactive'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one more question, don't want to make new thread. How can i use identify to point some point, and exclude it in next plotting?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this piece of code

```
minx <- which(df$LakeHuron == minimum)
maxx <- which(df$LakeHuron == maximum)
points(x = 1874 + minx,minimum, col = "red")
points(x = 1874 + maxx,maximum, col = "red")
```

I've used the points function to plot points on your graph. You could change its visual. To that, see the page [website](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/rw1001/library/base/html/points.html)

Comment: also see `which.min()` and `which.max()`